# Angular universal rendering only css and no html

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I have an Angular universal project up and running and it work correctly but in the page source of the browser I only see CSS outputted and no HTML. Am I missing something?

[Page source screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6I8T.png)

Answer (score 0):

In order to know what is going on you should give a bit more of information. 
The only thing that I can think of looking at your screenshot, is that the path of the url in your browser isn't matching any of the routes configured in your angular app.

For more info, you can go to https://angular.io/guide/router